# Displaying users avatars from reddit API crashes when changing subreddit (1 out of 2 times) in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reddit

I have managed to fetch users avatars from Reddit API without OAuth2 and display them in posts, but the app crashes when changing subreddit 1 out of 2 times. I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'snoovatar_img' of undefined. I think it's related to the fact that the userInfo component needs postId prop from the post component to load avatars. If it doesn't get the postId on time, then the fetched user data is undefined. And since I render the UserInfo component inside of the post component, it becomes a closed circle. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Here's my request to fetch posts (it updates every time subreddit is changed):

```
export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchPosts', async(subreddit) => {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_ROOT}${subreddit}.json`)
      const dataRow = await response.json()
      return dataRow.data.children.map((post) => post.data)
    })
```

Here's how I fetch user data  (it also updates every time subreddit is changed):

```
export const controlFetching = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchUsers', async(subreddit) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/${subreddit}.json`)
  const posts = await response.json();
  const authors = posts.data.children.map((post) => post.data.author)
  let allResponse = []
// **it takes each user's name and passes it in the second request to get avatars. The request returns loads of objects with user data so I pushed them all in one array**
      for (let i = 0; i <= authors.length-1; i++) {
  const userData = await fetch(`${API_ROOT}/user/${authors[i]}/about.json`).then(response1 => response1.json())
      allResponse.push( userData.data)}
      return allResponse
})
```

Here's the UserInfo component which accepts postId as prop to find the user corresponding to the post and renders users avatarts.

```
export const UserInfo = ({postId}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const userStatus = useSelector(state => state.users.userStatus)
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.users.userError)
  const selectedSubreddit = useSelector(state => state.posts.selectedSubreddit)

  const user = useSelector((state) => selectUsersById(state, postId))


useEffect(()=> {
  
  dispatch(controlFetching(selectedSubreddit)) }
, [selectedSubreddit, dispatch]);
 
  let userContent 

  if (userStatus === 'loading') {
      userContent = <div>Loading...</div>
  } else if (userStatus === 'succeeded'){
      userContent = 
      <img 
         src={`${user.snoovatar_img.length !==0 ? user.snoovatar_img : avatar }`}
         alt={`${user.snoovatar_img.length !==0 ? user.snoovatar_img : 'avatar' } profile`}
         className="avatar-profile-image"  />
   
    } else if (userStatus === 'failed'){
        userContent = <div>{error}</div>
    }
    return (
      <section>
        {userContent}
      </section>
    ) 
  }
```

Here's the PostsList component that renders posts and avatars in it.

```
let PostContent = ({postId}) => {
  const post = useSelector((state) => selectPostById(state, postId))
  
  return (
    <article  className="post-content" key={post.id}>
      <div className="userInfo">

        <UserInfo postId={postId} />
       
         <h5 id='home' className="userName"> by  {post.author}</h5>
      </div>
      <div className="postContent">
        <h3 className="post-title">{post.title}</h3>
        <img className="post-image" src={post.url} alt=""/>
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export const PostsList = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const postStatus = useSelector(state => state.posts.status)
  const orderedPostIds = useSelector(selectPostIds)
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.posts.error)
  const selectedSubreddit = useSelector(state => state.posts.selectedSubreddit)

  useEffect(()=> {
    
      dispatch(fetchPosts(selectedSubreddit))
  }, [selectedSubreddit, dispatch]);

    let content 

    if (postStatus=== 'loading') {
      content = <div>Loading...</div>
    } else if(postStatus === 'succeeded'){
      content = orderedPostIds.map((postId)=> 
    ( <PostContent postId = {postId} key={postId}/>
    ))
    } else if(postStatus === 'failed'){
      content = <div>{error}</div>
    }
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Posts</h2>
        {content}
      </section>
    ) 
  }
```

I also get warnings like so : ImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware took 33ms, which is more than the warning threshold of 32ms. Will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't making sure that the `user` variable exists before accessing properties on it.  You are trusting `userStatus` to do this but it's clearly unreliable.

Change

```
else if (userStatus === 'succeeded') {
```

to

```
else if (userStatus === 'succeeded' && user) {
```

Which makes sure that the `user` variable is something [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

The fetch itself is just based on the `selectedSubreddit`, not the `postId`, so there shouldn't be an issue there if the `postId` changes later.

---

I [reworked your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/reddit-api-json-with-redux-toolkit-829h3?file=/src/components/App.tsx) and made it so that we are fetching each user through its own action rather than trying to fetch all of the users at once.  We can just pass the `username` as an argument.  It doesn't make sense to me that the `UserInfo` component should depend on the `postId` instead of the `username` when both of those are contained in the post JSON.

action

```
export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchUser",
  async (username: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.reddit.com/user/${username}/about.json`
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    return json.data;
  }
);
```

component

```
export const UserInfo = ({ username }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector((state) => selectUserByUsername(state, username));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      dispatch(fetchUser(username));
    }
  }, [username, dispatch, user]);

  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <img
        src={`${user.snoovatar_img || user.icon_img}`} // empty string evaluates as false
        alt={`user ${username} profile`}
        className="avatar-profile-image"
      />
    </section>
  );
};
```

in `PostContent`

```
<UserInfo username={post.author} />
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! it seems to be so obvious now :)

Comment: I've got another issue; it's that the avatar gets updated a lot of times before it finally loads on the page. I know that it's probably because I used push method in the fetch request and it updates the state every time a new object is pushed to the state. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a CodeSandbox with your code?  I’d like to play with it.

Comment: [I had fun playing with this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mcnulty-829h3?file=/src/components/UserInfo.tsx) the main differences are that I am a fetching every user individually and I am basing it off the username rather than the post id.

Comment: I changed my avatar fetch, the way you did it makes much more sense. here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bird-mymko?file=/src/features/avatar/avatarSlice.js). I've got another issue now! When I go to a single post like /posts/mlxft5 and refresh the page it says that the post is not found. I understand more or less  why it does it but can't figure out how to fix it. Maybe you would have an idea? @Linda Paiste

Comment: You need to create an action that can fetch a single post from the API based on the id.  In the single post page you need to use a useEffect to dispatch that action.  Ideally you want to only fetch that post if you haven’t already fetched it (including from the subreddit list).  Here’s a long answer I just wrote yesterday that explains the conditional fetching: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977741/10431574